# Getting Status 404 from HTTPResponse, Angular8

Tags: node.js, angular8

I am creating a CRUD application using RestAPI. I know this question has been asked in stack overflow many times but I have seen many answers to this question that are not fixing my error. 
Actually I am adding a product using RestAPI and for this, I am using get() method which is obvious. HTTPResponse always returned status 404 on Uri localhost:4200.
Please help me with this problem I am stuck in this problem from last night.

**Product.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:4200/products';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice) {
    console.log(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice);
    const obj = {
      ProductName,
      ProductDescription,
      ProductPrice
    };
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}/add`, obj)
        .subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this
           .http
           .get(`${this.uri}`);
  }

  editProduct(id) {
    return this
            .http
            .get(`${this.uri}/edit/${id}`);
  }

  updateProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice, id) {
    const obj = {
      ProductName,
      ProductDescription,
      ProductPrice
    };
    this
      .http
      .post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj)
      .subscribe(res => console.log('Update Complete'));
  }

  deleteProduct(id) {
    return this
              .http
              .get(`${this.uri}/delete/${id}`);
  }
}
```

**App-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductAddComponent } from './product-add/product-add.component';
import { ProductEditComponent } from './product-edit/product-edit.component';
import { ProductGetComponent } from './product-get/product-get.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'product/create',
    component: ProductAddComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    component: ProductEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductGetComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**This is error message which is called on creatig a new Product**
[image: This is error message which is called on creatig a new Product]

Comment: Stackoverflow has feature to format code. So, please remove your screenshot of code and add the actual code in the question. Also, where is your server side code?

Comment: Which one is the server side code? I believe these are not server side code. Where did you define your route? You are requesting to a route that doesn't exists.

Comment: That URL does not exist on your  server that's what it's says